# Run spray-servlet war gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class

Tags: web-applications, spray

Just as in question title. I build .war with spray-servlet. I try to deploy it on jetty and jboss-7, but both give me the same error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at spray.http.Uri$Query.<init>(Uri.scala:496)
at spray.http.Uri$Query$Empty$.<init>(Uri.scala:575)
at spray.http.Uri$Query$Empty$.<clinit>(Uri.scala)
at spray.http.parser.UriParser.<init>(UriParser.scala:37)
at spray.http.Uri$.apply(Uri.scala:231)
at spray.http.Uri$.apply(Uri.scala:203)
at spray.http.Uri$.<init>(Uri.scala:194)
at spray.http.Uri$.<clinit>(Uri.scala)
at spray.http.Uri$Path$.build$1(Uri.scala:427)
at spray.http.Uri$Path$.apply(Uri.scala:428)
at spray.servlet.ConnectorSettings$.fromSubConfig(ConnectorSettings.scala:52)
at spray.servlet.ConnectorSettings$.fromSubConfig(ConnectorSettings.scala:46)
at spray.util.SettingsCompanion.apply(SettingsCompanion.scala:50)
at spray.servlet.Initializer$$anonfun$contextInitialized$1.apply$mcV$sp(Initializer.scala:40)
at akka.util.Switch.transcend(LockUtil.scala:27)
at akka.util.Switch.switchOn(LockUtil.scala:48)
at spray.servlet.Initializer.contextInitialized(Initializer.scala:33)
....
```

I checked in the .war and there is WEB-INF/lib/scala-library-2.11.0.jar, so the class should be accessible. What can be the cause of the error?

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction and post it on the mailing list? In the best case, fork the spray-template repo and upgrade it to Scala 2.11 and then provide instructions how reproduce the problem with a standalone container.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the very same error message with a different setup. I was using spray-client in a standalone app (no JBoss).

The cause was that although I was using Spray 1.3.1 which is supposed to run on Scala 2.11 the version I was actually getting from the Maven repo (I use Maven in my project) was built against Scala 2.10. Check out the [POM](http://repo.spray.io/io/spray/spray-client/1.3.1/spray-client-1.3.1.pom) if you want to see for yourself.

So, what I did to fix it was

1. add the Spray repo to the list of repositories

> ```
> <repositories>
>     <repository>
>         <id>spray</id>
>         <name>Spray IO</name>
>         <url>http://repo.spray.io</url>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
> ```

1. Switch to a nightly(?) build of Spray 1.3.1

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spray-client_2.11</artifactId>
>     <version>1.3.1-20140423</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

For SBT that would be

> ```
> "io.spray" %% "spray-client" % "1.3.1-20140423"
> ```

**Update**: Not sure if that was there before or the just added it recently, but the [Spray homepage](http://spray.io/project-info/current-versions/) now also suggests to use that version.